# How to search parent Node of a given Node in a non variant Binary Tree?

Tags: c, search, data-structures, binary-tree

I have the code for searching a node in a Binary Tree. How can I find the parent of the Node whose `KEY` is provided as an argument?

Here is the code for Normal search for a Binary Tree -

```
struct Tree* search(struct Tree *root, int KEY)
{
    struct Tree *temp;
    if(root == NULL) return NULL; //Base condition
    else
    {
        if(root-> data == KEY) return root;
        else
        {
            temp = search(root-> Lchild, KEY);
            if(temp != NULL) return temp;
            else return(search(root-> Rchild, KEY));
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-parent-of-a-node-in-the-given-binary-tree/

Comment: No. This code just prints the parent. I want a code which returns it

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the address of the `Tree` node whose value matches with the `KEY`, not it's parent. Assuming that all the node values are distinct in this tree, you have to follow the below code to return the parent `Tree` node address if it's child node (left or right child) value matches with the `KEY`.

```
struct Tree* search(struct Tree *root, int KEY){
    if(root == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    if(root->Lchild != NULL && root->Lchild->data == KEY){
        return root;
    }
    if(root->Rchild != NULL && root->Rchild->data == KEY){
        return root;
    }
    struct Tree *left = search(root->Lchild, KEY);
    struct Tree *right = search(root->Rchild, KEY);
    if(left != NULL){
        return left;
    }else if(right != NULL){
        return right;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```